# Is there a shorter way to derive this simple delimited array of integers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been writing a few CSV exports today, and I can't think of a simpler more elegant way to write this :

```
numbered_questions = ''
question_count.times{|i| numbered_questions << (i + 1).to_s + (i ==  (question_count - 1) ? '' : ',')}
```

So essentially if my `question_count` was `5`, then my result would be :

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

Anyone know a shorter way to derive the same result from the input of a dynamic integer?

Comment: Can you tell me the logic.. Your code is very complex.. :(

Comment: I agree - some example inputs and outputs would be useful.

Comment: So if I have the dynamic number of `3`, then I would want `1,2,3`, or or if I had `4`, I would want `1,2,3,4`. Both results should be a String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Range` can be `String`:

```
=> ("1".."5").to_a*','
=> "1,2,3,4,5"
```

and more short:

```
=> [*"1".."5"]*','
=> "1,2,3,4,5"
```

fisrt `*` is `splat` operator, last `*` repetition — with a String argument, equivalent to `ary.join(str)` Otherwise, returns a new array built by concatenating the int copies of `self`.

Comment: Whoa, I've never seen an astrisk used this way. What does that mean?

Comment: just `splat` operator.

Comment: I have to give it you, this is the *shortest* answer.

Comment: be attention this about `String` not `Integer`. i post this just for example.

Comment: But it works with integers as well. `(1..5).to_a*','`

Comment: @Trip i add annotation

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but if it's just to make an array of numbers from 1 to N then you can do

```
(1..N).to_a
```

if you want it as a string then do

```
(1..N).to_a.join(",")
```

Comment: That is brilliant and right on target. Thank you so much Max Williams.

Comment: cool. btw `1..N` is a `Range` object.  http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html